# Why does my screen turn itself ON?

Tags: screen, wakelock

I am having a problem with my phone's screen arbitrarily turning itself on.  It has been going on for a while, but I finally got a logcat of it, so here it is.  If anyone can find anything in here that looks like it is causing the problem, and how to resolve it, please let me know.

I'm particularly suspicious of the first entry at `10-01 18:25:44.411` and the other entries that say `E/power`, but I don't know what to make of the rest.

```
10-01 18:25:32.079 D/PowerManagerService(  279): Screen__Off : releaseWakeLockLocked flags=0x0 tag=AdControllerWakeLock myUID=1000 myPID=279 myTID=505
10-01 18:25:32.079 I/PowerManagerService(  279): Ulight 7->0|0
10-01 18:25:32.079 D/PowerManagerService(  279): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
10-01 18:25:32.129 V/MmsProvider(  425): Query uri=content://mms/inbox, match=2
10-01 18:25:32.300 D/dalvikvm(  279): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2041K, 47% free 10031K/18759K, external 11107K/12124K, paused 9ms+8ms
10-01 18:25:32.300 D/StagefrightPlayer(  181): reset
10-01 18:25:32.300 D/StagefrightPlayer(  181): reset over
10-01 18:25:32.300 D/StagefrightPlayer(  181): reset
10-01 18:25:32.300 D/StagefrightPlayer(  181): reset over
10-01 18:25:32.330 D/dalvikvm( 1425): GC_CONCURRENT freed 503K, 47% free 3365K/6279K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-01 18:25:32.360 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault( 2143): (thUse=11) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
10-01 18:25:32.360 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - GbaSupportIndicatorRequestUpdaterDefault( 2143): (thUse=11) GbaSupportIndicatorRequestUpdaterAbstract() userHeaderPredefined=null
10-01 18:25:32.430 D/dalvikvm( 2143): GC_CONCURRENT freed 378K, 49% free 3115K/6023K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+2ms
10-01 18:25:32.440 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault( 2143): (thUse=11)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null
10-01 18:25:32.440 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault( 2143): (thUse=11)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.
10-01 18:25:32.440 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl( 2143): (thUse=11) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false
10-01 18:25:32.440 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl( 2143): (thUse=11) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false
10-01 18:25:32.440 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault( 2143): (thUse=11)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.
10-01 18:25:32.440 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault( 2143): (thUse=11) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
10-01 18:25:32.440 I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=11) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler( 2143): (thUse=11)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
10-01 18:25:32.570 V/DATA    (  425): [DCT(0) ] intent received :android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
10-01 18:25:32.570 D/WallpaperService(  279): ACTION_SCREEN_ON
10-01 18:25:32.580 D/PhoneUtils(  425): updateRAFT() : FactoryMode : false
10-01 18:25:32.740 D/dalvikvm( 2143): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 300K, 52% free 2928K/6023K, external 0K/0K, paused 34ms
10-01 18:25:32.750 D/DATA    (  425): [DSST(0)] pollstate() : reason = data network state changed
10-01 18:25:32.840 E/power   (  279): *** set_screen_state 0
10-01 18:25:32.840 I/PowerManagerService(  279): Light Animator Finished curIntValue=0
10-01 18:25:32.840 D/PowerManagerService(  279): enableLightSensor false
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/SensorManager(  279): unregisterListener:: disable all sensors for this listener,  name = GP2A Light Sensor listener = com.android.server.PowerManagerService$13@4052ad40
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): onScreenTurnedOff(3)
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): notifyScreenOffLocked
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): resetStateLocked
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): handleNotifyScreenOff
10-01 18:25:32.850 I/OrientationDebug(  279): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/LockPatternKeyguardView(  279): onScreenTurnedOff()
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): handleReset
10-01 18:25:32.850 V/OrientationDebug(  279): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=false, current orientation=5, SensorEnabled=false
10-01 18:25:32.850 W/PowerManagerService(  279): CurLockF mPS:0 mUS=0
10-01 18:25:32.850 W/PowerManagerService(  279): type=PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK              'RILJ' active (mS=0)  activeT=20
10-01 18:25:32.850 W/PowerManagerService(  279): type=PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK              'sleep_broadcast' active (mS=0)  activeT=3
10-01 18:25:32.850 W/PowerManagerService(  279): mPokeLocks.size=0:
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/PowerManagerService(  279): sendNotificationLocked on=false
10-01 18:25:32.850 D/PowerManagerService(  279): mNotificationTask : off
10-01 18:25:32.850 V/WindowManager(  279): Setting event dispatching to false
10-01 18:25:32.870 D/VoldCmdListener(  173): volume shared /mnt/sdcard ums
10-01 18:25:32.870 D/MountService(  279): doGetVolumeShared :: path = /mnt/sdcard, method = ums, result = false
10-01 18:25:32.870 D/VoldCmdListener(  173): volume shared /mnt/sdcard/external_sd ums
10-01 18:25:32.880 D/dalvikvm(  425): GC_EXPLICIT freed 351K, 41% free 4104K/6919K, external 0K/1280K, paused 48ms
10-01 18:25:32.880 D/MountService(  279): doGetVolumeShared :: path = /mnt/sdcard/external_sd, method = ums, result = false
10-01 18:25:32.880 D/MountService(  279):  :::: isUsbMassStorageEnabled :: ret = false
10-01 18:25:32.890 D/StatusBarService(  407): animateCollapse() - updateViewLayout
10-01 18:25:32.910 D/DATA    (  425): [DSST(0)] Poll ServiceState done: oldSS=[0 home null null null  HSPA CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false] newSS=[0 home null null null  HSPA CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false]
10-01 18:25:32.910 V/DATA    (  425): [DCT(0) ] intent received :android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
10-01 18:25:32.920 D/WallpaperService(  279): ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
10-01 18:25:32.930 D/PhoneUtils(  425): updateRAFT() : FactoryMode : false
10-01 18:25:32.990 D/SurfaceFlinger(  279): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x88720
10-01 18:25:33.601 D/BatteryService(  279): update start
10-01 18:25:33.601 D/BatteryService(  279): US/CANADA GSM Models
10-01 18:25:33.601 D/BatteryService(  279): updateBattery level:37 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 3811 temperature: 283 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17302234
10-01 18:25:33.631 D/PhoneUtils(  425): updateRAFT() : FactoryMode : false
10-01 18:25:34.412 E/AlarmManagerService(  279): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=0, 1349130344.397000000
10-01 18:25:34.412 V/AlarmManager(  279): Adding alarm Alarm{40d4f110 type 0 com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.GalaxySTheme} at 0
10-01 18:25:35.202 E/AlarmManagerService(  279): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=1, 1349130355.212000000
10-01 18:25:35.202 V/AlarmManager(  279): Adding alarm Alarm{411a20e8 type 1 com.tecace.tetheringmanager} at 0
10-01 18:25:35.202 V/AlarmManager(  279): sending alarm Alarm{411a20e8 type 1 com.tecace.tetheringmanager}
10-01 18:25:35.233 I/TetheringManagerService( 1885): Running time = 40 seconds
10-01 18:25:40.297 D/dalvikvm( 2109): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 48% free 3321K/6343K, external 0K/0K, paused 63ms
10-01 18:25:44.391 E/AlarmManagerService(  279): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=0, 1349130387.981000000
10-01 18:25:44.391 V/AlarmManager(  279): sending alarm Alarm{40d4f110 type 0 com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.GalaxySTheme}
10-01 18:25:44.391 V/AlarmManager(  279): pending wakeup alarm com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.GalaxySTheme
10-01 18:25:44.411 E/power   (  279): *** set_screen_state 1
10-01 18:25:44.411 D/PowerManagerService(  279): reactivateScreenLocksLocked mProxIgnoredBecauseScreenTurnedOff=false
10-01 18:25:44.411 D/PowerManagerService(  279): Screen__On : acquireWakeLock flags=0x3000001a tag=AdControllerWakeLock uid=10147 pid=2143   myUID=1000 myPID=279 myTID=279
10-01 18:25:44.411 I/PowerManagerService(  279): Ulight 0->7|0
10-01 18:25:44.411 D/PowerManagerService(  279): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 237
10-01 18:25:44.421 D/SensorManager(  279): registerListener :: handle = 3  name= GP2A Light Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= com.android.server.PowerManagerService$13@4052ad40
10-01 18:25:44.421 D/PowerManagerService(  279): enableLightSensor true
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): onScreenTurnedOn, seq = 18
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): notifyScreenOnLocked
10-01 18:25:44.502 I/OrientationDebug(  279): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
10-01 18:25:44.502 V/OrientationDebug(  279): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=5, SensorEnabled=false
10-01 18:25:44.502 I/OrientationDebug(  279): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return false #3
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/KeyguardViewMediator(  279): handleNotifyScreenOn
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/LockPatternKeyguardView(  279): onScreenTurnedOn()
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/UnlockScreen(  279): max failed attempt for device disable :0
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/UnlockScreen(  279): isDeviceDisabledForMaxFailedAttempt return :false
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/PowerManagerService(  279): sendNotificationLocked on=true
10-01 18:25:44.502 D/PowerManagerService(  279): mNotificationTask : on
10-01 18:25:44.502 V/WindowManager(  279): Setting event dispatching to true
10-01 18:25:44.512 D/PowerManagerService(  279): acquireDVFSlock : level : 1,    timeMS : 3000
10-01 18:25:44.602 I/Notification(  784): package = com.gau.golauncherex.notification class = com.gau.golauncherex.notification.service.NotificationService
10-01 18:25:44.802 E/MP-Decision(  744): Error(-22) changing core status to online
10-01 18:25:44.812 I/PowerManagerService(  279): Light Animator Finished curIntValue=237
10-01 18:25:45.002 D/SurfaceFlinger(  279): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x88720
10-01 18:25:47.515 D/PowerManagerService(  279): acquireDVFSlock : level : -1,    timeMS : 100
10-01 18:25:47.595 E/power   (  279): release_cpu_max_lock() return -1
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the Galaxy S Theme is what was causing the problems.  Luckily, it was not a stock app, but one I downloaded, so I uninstalled it.  For now, I am reserving my accept for a few days to be sure that it has stopped happening.

Comment: Are you running some live wallpaper in which go launcher is using as theme? That could be a contributor to the screen turning itself on periodically, the alarm goes off as per in the logcat... my 2cents.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already pointed to the correct lines -- the interesting ones are the two immediately before it:

```
10-01 18:25:44.391 V/AlarmManager(  279): sending alarm Alarm{40d4f110 type 0 com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.GalaxySTheme}
10-01 18:25:44.391 V/AlarmManager(  279): pending wakeup alarm com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.GalaxySTheme
10-01 18:25:44.411 E/power   (  279): *** set_screen_state 1
```

So GoLauncher GalaxySTheme had requested a wakeup. I've read about similar issues before on another site with other GoLauncher components (cannot remember which ones it were -- but it were some I don't use myself). In your case, there seems to be something special with the Theme used. I take it you explicitly installed [GalaxyS GO Launcher EX Themes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.GalaxySTheme) (compare the apps package name in this url with the log message quoted above: Yes, this is the one having requested the wakeup). You could try to (temporarily) deactivate/remove this theme and see if this helps.

Comment: Yupp -- I cross all fingers for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Check if that happens with different launcher, if it doesn't you can try go launcher again with a different theme.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed any "Battery widget"? I am wondering would `E/power` refer to some battery widgets. I had the same problem before, after uninstalling all battery widgets and restart the phone, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag [`ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP) in `PowerManager`, which can be used by third-party apps to turn on the screen. I would suggest an easier way to find the cause by using [Wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) app from Google Play.
[More info about Wakelock](https://www.slideshare.net/ahikmat1/android-wakelock-detector)